# Is there a better way to remove elements from list using c#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects.  If any of the properties equal `null` I want that entire element removed from the list.  Is there a better way to do it then what I have below.

I've tried for loops and for each and either can't figure out how to do it or don't fully understand how to accomplish my task.

```
var i = 0;

while (i < filterCriterias.Count())
{
    if (filterCriterias[i].ColumnName == null 
        || filterCriterias[i].Comparator == null 
        || filterCriterias[i].Criteria == null)
    {
        filterCriterias.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

So if I have the list below:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order> 
{
    new Order {ColumnName = null, OperantOrder = null},
    new Order {ColumnName = Session, OperantOrder = ASC},
    new Order {ColumnName = null, OperantOrder = null},
}
```

I only want the list to only contain the element 1 where columnName = session and operantorder = asc.

Comment: If you are going to use this method, you really should be going through the list backwards, or you could potentially end up skipping items / going past the end of the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more idiomatic approach would be to use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
filterCriterias.RemoveAll(c => c.ColumnName == null ||
                               c.Comparator == null ||
                               c.Criteria == null);
```

Comment: Thank for the edit, E. Moffat. Stupid typo on my behalf :-(

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of removing just select what you want using `System.Linq` like below. This will return a new collection.

```
var order = orders.Where(x => x.ColumnName == Session && x.OperantOrder == ASC).ToList();
```

You can as well consider using `FirstOrDefault()` like

```
var order = orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnName == Session && x.OperantOrder == ASC);
```

Comment: This would create another list. Depending on what the OP means by "better" this could be "worse".

Answer (score 1):

To use a `for` loop when removing items from a list, it's normally best to start at the last element and work backwards. This way you don't end up skipping items or get an `IndexOutOfRange` exception because the `Count` changed during the loop (which happens when removing items in a forward direction):

```
// Start at the last index and move towards index '0'
for (int i = filterCriterias.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (filterCriterias[i].ColumnName == null ||
        filterCriterias[i].Comparator == null ||
        filterCriterias[i].Criteria == null)
    {
        filterCriterias.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```